# Adding constant powered outlet to existing switched circuit

Tags: electrical, switch

My apologies if this has been asked before. I searched and did not see anything matching what I am looking to do.

I am wanting to add a camera to my front porch and the only power is from a porch light controlled by a switch on the ceiling, so it will be easy to add a box.  I want to keep the light on the switch but would like to add and box with an always on outlet to power the camera.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how the wiring was done.  If power goes first to the porch light then to the switch, there will be always-hot up in the light box.

If power goes first to the switch then to the light, then it's likely the switch interrupts power to the light.  In that case you will need to bypass the switch and do one of the following:

- have the porch light operate on a photocell or motion sensor
- abandon the porch light
- go with any of a variety of smart-switch-control technologies that lets you put a receiver in the lamp base, and a transmitter in the switch location.  For instance the X10 system goes back to the 1980s. Or newer systems allow you to control the light from New Zealand with your phone.